# Is there any way to create WP archive page for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom taxonomy name "towers".
I'm trying to get to the "**[www.example.com/towers/**"](http://www.example.com/towers/**%22) page (not the "www.example.com/towers/abc" page),
but I'm reaching 404, page not found error.

I've done some reading and realize that this is not ordinary on WP. meaning that WP don't understand what Tower am I trying to access, and that is why they need me to use the full URL above.

And yet, are any of you familiar with some solution?

Comment: Without sounding harsh, you should continue to do research. This is a a pretty basic WP function. You probably need to refresh your permalinks, and possibly create either an archive page or a page template for your custom tax.

Comment: This is a very theme dependent question. So I suggest you research in relation to the theme you are using, as some themes eg Astra make it near impossible. But Howard is correct your issue may be just that you need to refresh your permalinks. Ie go to Settings --> Permalinks and click Save Changes. You don't need to change anything, but after adding a new post type this is essential. Also here is a good starting point for looking https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/